# iPhone: Reading a string from a file is returning the wrong results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file

**What I'm doing:**

I am reading some data off a file several times while my app runs. I use the following code to do so:

```
NSString *dataPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dataPath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation error:NULL];
NSArray *components = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"|||||"];
```

The first time this is called, it works as expected - I get an array of length 5, each section containing a relevant string.

**What goes wrong:**

This file is never modified. Yet, when I call the same procedure a second time (or third, fourth etc) I don't get the same result. Instead, an array of length 1 is returned, containing only part of the necessary data.

Why? I can't see any reason for this to go wrong... any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Change your name, you're ruining my rep ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the code works fine. The problem was elsewhere in my code, where I was (accidentally) accessing protected directories. As a result, iOS blocked my app from accessing any files at all :o

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is in you AppBundle this means that you can't modify this file at all.
Are you sure that, where ever this code is called, the autorelease object are retained correctly?

If you call this block of code every time you want this data, it might be an idea to save the results of the first time and use that every time. This will speed things up a bit.

Comment: True, it doesn't quite make sense to do this though as the containing object is released in-between file reading - and the file isn't that big anyway. I'll have a look at retains and releases etc when I get home :)